# Scala udf UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, scala, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe a2 written in scala :

```
val a3 = a2.select(printme.apply(col(“PlayerReference”)))
```

the column PlayerReference contains a string.

that calls an udf function :

```
val printme = udf({
      st: String =>
        val x = new JustPrint(st)
        x.printMe();
        
    })
```

this udf function calls a java class :

```
public class JustPrint {
    private String ss = null;
    
    public JustPrint(String ss) {
        this.ss = ss;
    }
    
    public void printMe() {
        System.out.println("Value : " + this.ss);
    }
}
```

but i have this error for the udf :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Unit is not supported
```

The goal of this exercise is to validate the chain of calls.
What should I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: your UDF returns `Unit` method `printMe()` has `void` return type which is `Unit` type in scala. In `spark` User Defined Functions should return `non-Unit` type. If you want to print some data, maybe it's better to use `Dataframe` `show`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is that your UDF doesn't return anything, which, in terms of spark is called Unit.

What you should do depends on what you actually want, but, assuming you just want to track values coming through your UDF you should either change printMe so it returns String, or the UDF.
Like this:

```
public String printMe() {
    System.out.println("Value : " + this.ss);
    return this.ss;
}
```

or like this:

```
val printme = udf({
  st: String =>
    val x = new JustPrint(st)
    x.printMe();
    x
})
```